# Is there a way to save the value printed in the console into a file?

Tags: c

trying to make a program that reads a continuous stream of data from a microcontroller with a long press of a button I could read a stream of data.

everything works well and I can see the expected data output in the console when I print it, but when I try to save it in a file both the value saved in the file, and the value in the console are both wrong, but when I comment out the file handling code the console output is correct again.

Is there a way to save the value printed in the console into a file?

this is what i did for the button press, console print, and file handling side of the program

```
 
   D1 = strtol(arrayin, 0, 2);
   D2 = strtol(arrayin, 0, 2);

    struct pollfd mypoll;
    mypoll.fd =0;
    mypoll.events = POLLIN;

 if(poll(&mypoll, 1, 0)==1){
    press_button = getchar();
  if(press_button==97){
   printf("%x\t, %x\t", D1, D2); 

   char array1[100]; 
    FILE* file_ready;
    file_ready = fopen("Output_data.csv", "ab+");
    sprintf(array1, "0x%x\t, 0x%x\n", D1, D2);
    fputs(array1, file_ready);
    fclose(file_ready);
   
   }
 }
```

Comment: This does not look like C# at all. (I removed the tag, please [edit] question explaining how it relates to C# if you believe my update was wrong)

Comment: Do you want to print the value from within the software? Or you want to redirect the console to a file? The question is a bit confusing from the POV of what you actually want.

Comment: You did not give us the type definitions, so I have to guess some things. If you have some value wrong (which one, actual value, expected value...) then maybe the "%x" in "sprintf()" should be "%lx" - the line "D1 = strtol(arrayin, 0, 2);" suggests that D1 is a long integer, not an integer.

Comment: Additionally, you can use a debugger and run the SW step by step, and understand what happens.

Comment: Remove `sprintf` and `fputs` and see what happens.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Please provide a [mre]. Please check the returned `file` pointer. Why do you set the file mode to binary, as you write text to it? -- Please [edit] your question if you clarify, this is not a forum.